# What is the difference between “||” and “or” in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between "||" and "or"?

```
a = false || true;
b = false or true;
```

Comment: `or` is a synonym for `||`.   `||` isn't supported with all non-ISO-646 character sets.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `¦¦` because of all the time I programmed on an IBM PC in the early 1980s.  But that's not vogue anymore, and some characters have been moved around since that era of ANSI.

Comment: Why downvotes?.

Answer (score 1):

there are no difference, 
see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/or

sometime (question of taste) may enforce readability (no confusion with |)

Answer (score 1):

There are a group of alternative tokens specified in the standard<sup>(a)</sup>, which equate to primary tokens. One of these is `or` for the `||` token.

As per `C++11/14 2.6 Alternative tokens` and `C++17/20 5.5 Alternative tokens` (wording has remained the same across all these iterations of the standard):

> In *all* respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token, except for its spelling.

That's my emphasis to indicate that there is *no* real difference at all.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As of C++17 (the most recent accepted standard at the time of this answer), the list of alternative tokens and their primaries is:

```
Alt Prim         Alt    Prim        Alt    Prim
--- ----         ---    ----        ---    ----
<%   {           and    &&          and_eq &=
%>   }           bitor  |           or_eq  |=
<:   [           or     ||          xor_eq ^=
:>   ]           xor    ^           not    !
%:   #           compl  ~           not_eq !=
%:%: ##          bitand &
```

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all. `or` is simply an alternative keyword for `||`.

See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative